# Show elements when I click a HTML button using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make some text (three dessert names that the user inputs) pop up when I click a button. this is my code

```
<body>
    <p>your dessert</p>
    <input type="text" class="yum1">
        <p>your dessert</p>
    <input type="text" class="yum2">
        <p>your dessert</p>
    <input type="text" class="yum3">
</body>
```

can you please give me a CSS (cascading style sheets) code?
if not then give me a JS (javascript) code. btw I don't know js :(

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Where is the button? Do you want the inputs to show/hide or only the text the user input to popup?

Comment: the button is at the bottom and I want the input box AND the text to popup

Comment: Relax, we are not sitting here pressing reload reload in case you answered the comment

Comment: ok. this is exactly what I want.

Comment: It is still completely unclear what you want. Add the button to your question and draw a picture and give step by step what the user needs to do and what he sees

Comment: I want the words your dessert then a input box then your dessert then a input box then your dessert the a input box then a button that shows what you "inputed".

Comment: What did you try after you [investigated](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+show+input+value+in+a+div+site%3Astackoverflow.com)?

Comment: what is the name of button, basically purpose of it?

Comment: here is a link :https://codepen.io/krewson/pen/GRZrmLo?editors=1100. this is what I want:https://codepen.io/krewson/pen/KKzamYy

Comment: why is it taking so long

Comment: Did you read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting the exact purpose of your button clearly, but if you need the text you've inserted in the input box to pop-up in an alert box, you can assign id's to your input boxes and button then add an eventListner to the button which will display the alert boxes with the input fields.

Assigning ids to HTML elements:

```
<body>
    <p> your dessert
    <input type="text" id='dessert'></p>
        <p> your dessert
    <input type="text" id='dessert2'></p>
        <p> your dessert
    <input type="text" id='dessert3'></p>
    <button id='myButton'> your products</button>
</body
```

Js to display alert boxes:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", ()=> {

    var dessert = document.getElementById("dessert").value;
    var dessert2 = document.getElementById("dessert2").value;
    var dessert3 = document.getElementById("dessert3").value;
    alert( dessert);
    alert( dessert2);
    alert( dessert3);
});
```

I am not sure if there's a way you can compile all the inputs in one alert box but this way will display three alert boxes. Here is also a [pen](https://codepen.io/JuniorAdadie/pen/JjXEJPV) of the code.

Cheers...

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the classes you had assigned to the elements, you can still use them instead of the ids, though; remember to use document.getElementByClassName('') in js.

Comment: exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Code to show #myDesserts div on button click

```js
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('#yourProduct')

buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const myDesertsElement = document.querySelector('#myDesserts')
  const desert1Val = document.querySelector('#yum1').value
  const desert2Val = document.querySelector('#yum2').value
  const desert3Val = document.querySelector('#yum3').value
  myDesertsElement.classList.toggle('hide')
  myDesertsElement.innerHTML = `Your inputs: ${desert1Val} ${desert2Val} ${desert3Val}`
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>your dessert</p>
  <input id="yum1" type="text" class="yum1">
  <p>your dessert</p>
  <input id="yum2" type="text" class="yum2">
  <p>your dessert</p>
  <input id="yum3" type="text" class="yum3">
  <button id="yourProduct">your product</button>
  <div id="myDesserts" class="hide"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: oh sorry. I mean that you should output what they inputed

Comment: @DrakeKrewson can you check now?

Comment: what do you mean by check

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, if you are looking for :

*when user click on a button, then three dessert names (with user inputs option) will display, else hide.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class ="hide" id="options">
  <p>your dessert 1</p>
  <input type="text" class="yum1">
  <p>your dessert 2</p>
  <input type="text" class="yum2">
  <p>your dessert 3</p>
  <input type="text" class="yum3">
  </div>
 <br/> <br/>
 <button id="yourProduct" onclick= reveal()>Input your choice of dessert</button>
</body>
<script>
function reveal(){
const buttonEvent = document.querySelector("#yourProduct")
const dessertOptions = document.querySelector("#options")
buttonEvent.onClick = dessertOptions.classList.toggle("hide")
}
</script>
<style>
.hide{
height:0px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</html>
```